# Create dynamic variable name in XSLT or how can you solve this problem?

Tags: xml, xslt, text, xslt-1.0

I have a problem extrating some data out of this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ph:Graphs xmlns:ph="http://www.merge.something.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ph:Graph name="mass_spring_mo">
    <ph:Element id="0" type="Fixed">
        <ph:Port id="1" type="port">
            <ph:Attribute>
                <ph:AttributeField name="type" value="string"/>
                <ph:AttributeField name="name" value="type"/>
                <ph:AttributeField name="value" value="flange"/>
            </ph:Attribute>
        </ph:Port>
    </ph:Element>
    <ph:Element id="2" type="Spring">
        <ph:Attribute>
            <ph:AttributeField name="type" value="int"/>
            <ph:AttributeField name="name" value="s_rel0"/>
            <ph:AttributeField name="value" value="5"/>
        </ph:Attribute>
        <ph:Port id="3" type="port">
            <ph:Attribute>
                <ph:AttributeField name="type" value="string"/>
                <ph:AttributeField name="name" value="type"/>
                <ph:AttributeField name="value" value="flange_a"/>
            </ph:Attribute>
        </ph:Port>
    </ph:Element>
    <ph:Edge id="17" sourceid="1" targetid="3"/>
</ph:Graph>
</ph:Graphs>
```

Therefore I created this XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ph="http://www.merge.something.com">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:Graphs/ph:Graph"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Graph">
        <xsl:text>model </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>  
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:Element"/>
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text> 
        <xsl:text>equation</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:Edge"/>
        <xsl:text>end </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Element">
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="@type"/>
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>

        <xsl:text>Components.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
        <xsl:text > </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/><xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:Port/ph:Attribute"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Port/ph:Attribute">
        <xsl:if test="ph:AttributeField/@value=type">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:AttributeField"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:AttributeField">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Edge">
        <xsl:text>connect(</xsl:text>
         <xsl:text >);</xsl:text>
         <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should look like that:

```
model mass_spring_mo
 Components.Fixed fixed1;
 Components.Spring spring1(s_rel0 = 10);
equation  
 connect(fixed1.flange,spring1.flange_a);
end mass_spring_mo;
```

My problem is to get the correspondent name and type of the elements which should be connected. I tried to generate variable with an dynamic name like the id=1 but it doesn't work.
Maybe there is an easier solution to refer to the properties of the element!?

If anyone could give me a hint, I would be very grateful.

Thanks,
Bye Michele

Comment: You haven't explained anything. What is meant by "the elements which should be connected"? What is the semantics of this XML document? It isn't clear at all. In its current form this is not a well-defined question. Please, edit/improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a template.
You can see that I used a different method for line endings than you did.
Also the look back is done by defining the SourceElement and TargetElement variables in the ph:Edge template.  I just select the ph:Element element with the corresponding ph:Port child with an id that matches the sourceid attribute of the ph:Edge.  Once you can identify those, referencing their properties is easy enough.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ph="http://www.merge.something.com">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:Graphs/ph:Graph"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Graph">
        <xsl:text>model </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:Element"/>
        <xsl:text>equation&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:Edge"/>
        <xsl:text>end </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Element">
        <xsl:text> Components.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@type"/><xsl:text > </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(@type, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/><xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:Attribute"/>
        <xsl:text>;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Element/ph:Attribute">
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="ph:AttributeField[@name = 'type' and @value='int']">
              <xsl:text>(</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ph:AttributeField[@name = 'name']/@value"/><xsl:text> = </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ph:AttributeField[@name = 'value']/@value" /><xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="ph:AttributeField[@name = 'type' and @value='string']">
              <xsl:text>(</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ph:AttributeField[@name = 'name']/@value"/><xsl:text> = '</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="ph:AttributeField[@name = 'value']/@value" /><xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
           </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Port/ph:Attribute">
        <xsl:if test="ph:AttributeField/@value=type">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ph:AttributeField"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:AttributeField">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ph:Edge">
        <xsl:variable name="sourceid" select="@sourceid"/>
        <xsl:variable name="targetid" select="@targetid"/>
        <xsl:variable name="SourceElement" select="//ph:Element[ph:Port[@id = $sourceid]]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="TargetElement" select="//ph:Element[ph:Port[@id = $targetid]]"/>
        <xsl:text> connect(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($SourceElement/@type, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$SourceElement/@id" />
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$SourceElement/ph:Port/ph:Attribute/ph:AttributeField[@name = 'value']/@value" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($TargetElement/@type, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$TargetElement/@id" />
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$TargetElement/ph:Port/ph:Attribute/ph:AttributeField[@name = 'value']/@value" />
        <xsl:text >);&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good one! I think it would be even better to extract the identifier construction (with the `translate(…)`) into a separate template (passing the appropriate `ph:Element` node as parameter), perhaps even using variables `$uppercase` and `$lowercase` for readability…

Comment: Thank you so much Will for your answer, it works find. I've an additional question: how can I handle the `<attributes>`of a `ph:Element` if there are more than one but the output should look like `(s_rel0 = 10, var2 = 12)`. And if there are more `ph:Port` attributes as well!?

Comment: More ph:Port should be handled already as it is matching on the id attribute of the port.  As for the multiple ph:Element/ph:Attribute, you'd have to move some stuff to the ph:Element template like the ( and ).  I'd also probably do a foreach ph:Attribute so you could insert the comma.